# Azure powershell role assisgment using cloudshell and devops pipline

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-ad-graph-api, paas

I am trying to remove the assigement for a particular object id.Below is the error I am getting.
    I am attaching my service principal access level in AD.

When I am trying to exectute the same command using devops pipline I am getting different errror.

To remove the access what is the permission is required to my service prinicpal in API permission 
section only read can work ? and why I am geeting the clould.execption errror. Any advice.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce your issue, the command `Remove-AzRoleAssignment` will call the  [Azure AD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getobjectsbyobjectids-get-objects-from-a-list-of-object-ids--) to validate the `$objectid` you passed, so you need give the *Application permission* `Directory.Read.All` of Azure AD Graph(*not Microsoft Graph,not Delegated permission*).

[image]

After adding the permission, there is some delay(30m - 1h), then test the command, it works. (I test in local, the same in cloud shell)

[image]

**Note**: Except the permission in Azure AD, your service principal also need to have the permission in the subscription/specific resource scope, e.g. the servcie principal is the `Owner/User Access Admin` role in the `Access control (IAM)` of the subscription/specific resource scope(in your case, the storage account). If the service principal does not have the role, please add it as below.

[image]

---

In Azure Devops, you don't need to login with `Connect-AzAccount`(Actually in cloud shell, you also don’t need to login, but if you want to do so, it's also ok), it will login automatically with the service principal related to the service connection(`Task version >= 4.*`).

So please make sure the secret of your service principal is correct and the connection was verified. To run `Remove-AzRoleAssignment`, also add the permission above for the App Registration related to the service connection.

[image]

Then test it, it works.

[image]

Comment: Hi Joy you are correct my service principle key is not verified. After Verification I am able to assign the roles but still Microsoft.Azure.cloud.execption error is coming from the devops pipeline.For now in devops pipeline I set the option is continue, so that after role assignment my next devOps pipeline task shouldn't stop.

Comment: If  the api permission was granted, there may be some delay. I am sure it will work.

Comment: Hi joy not still cloud.authenication error, I have raised a MS ticket on that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Joy Wang is correct, but I would like to add that, you shouldn't give a service principal owner to the entire subscription if its not absolutely needed. its a security consideration. 
The better way would be to create a custom role in the subscription with only the permissions you need. in this case, some of the permissions you'll need to get it to work in the custom role are:

```
  "Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/read"
  "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/*"
  "Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/*"
```

Also, I tried to run get-azroleassignment without directory.read.all with a service principal, and it works as long as you have the role permissions assigned in the subscription. that leads me to believe the powershell get-add-remove-azroleassignment does not use the graph api permissions at all.

**Update**
As joy stated, its possible that the custom role may be useless as it could technically give itself ownership, however, here is proof that you dont need api graph permissions for the service principal to do this:

[image]

[image]

Update2: 
proof that removing the subscription rule, and only having api permissions does not work, it can only get the role assignments for itself, (the service principal itself) nothing else. 
[image]

Comment: The first part is correct, actually, adding the owner is for the actions you mentioned. The second part is wrong, when you use `Get/Remove-AzRoleAssignment` with a service principal, it must need the permission in AzureAD, the API permission or directory role both ok.

Comment: `I tried to run get-azroleassignment without directory.read.all with a service principal, and it works as long as you have the role permissions assigned in the subscription.` I suppose you test with a user account, not a service principal, the normal member user already has the permission to call this [AAD Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#getobjectsbyobjectids-get-objects-from-a-list-of-object-ids--), if you test with a serivice principal, you will get the error.

Comment: BTW, actually the custom role in this case is meaningless, becasue if you assign the custom role with the `Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/*` permission to the user, the user can also assign the other role e.g. `Owner` to himself.

Comment: that's a valid good point about the assigning itself owner. But about your other comment though, no I did NOT test with a user account. its a service principal. I have screenshots to prove it. it does not need api permissions, updated my post.

Comment: Your service principal may has a directory role, check it.

Comment: it has a custom subscription role. with those permissions. that's the whole point. that's the permission it needs to use those specific powershell commands. not api permissions. because i tried with api permissions only without the subscription role assignment, it did not work. when i tried with custom role subscription but with no api permissions, it works. that's proof enough for me. there is also no mention in the documentation for those powershell commands that it needs any "api permissions". updated with proof

Comment: Well, but I also test with a sp, it has the Owner role in the subscription, without the `api permission and directory role`, I reproduced the error. Anyway you can create a new sp to test again, I will keep my point.