# Azure Automation - Unable to get AzRoleAssignement

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-rbac

In order to automate some processes, I'm using **Azure Automation** with Owner rights for RunAsAccount.

```
$connection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection

while(!($connectionResult) -And ($logonAttempt -le 10))
{
    $LogonAttempt++
    # Logging in to Azure...
    $connectionResult =    Connect-AzAccount `
                               -ServicePrincipal `
                               -Tenant $connection.TenantID `
                               -ApplicationId $connection.ApplicationID `
                               -CertificateThumbprint $connection.CertificateThumbprint

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
    Write-Output $connectionResult
}

Get-AzRoleAssignment -ResourceGroupName $USERRGNAME -SignInName $USEREMAIL -verbos
```

An **error** is being thrown each time I execute the script:

```
Get-AzRoleAssignment: Cannot find principal using the specified options
```

Any idea to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to give **RunAsAccount** with the Application permission `Directory.Read.All` of the Azure AD Graph(not Microsoft Graph, not Delegated permission). By default, **RunAsAccount** doesn't have the Azure AD permission.

[image]

You could read [Joy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61919919/azure-powershell-role-assisgment-using-cloudshell-and-devops-pipline/61926235#61926235) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

This error is showing when there is no Role Assignment for name that is provided in the `SignInName` option.